# Can Asus Nexus 7 WiFi support a Huawei E3276 4G usb dongle SIM holder to achieve telephone functionality?

Tags: usb, nexus-7, sim-card, mobile-data

I could connect (with an usb adapter) a Huawei usb dongle that I normally use with my laptop computer and contains a SIM card for mobile internet and phone functions like SMS and phonecalls, but it doesn't seem that android (4.4.4) with my Asus Nexus 7 WiFi edition recognizes the device. Can it be done, or should I investigate other ways to enable mobile internet and telephony for my Asus Nexus 7?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you go forward with this and make any progress?

Comment: I didn't test it more. I think it's feasible to make it work with software interface. First I must fix a [random bug](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84664/how-to-resolve-asus-nexus-7-random-reboots) that reboots the thing. Thanks for comment!